# Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'

Tags: sql-server

I'm Fairly new to SQL so any help with this would be greatly appreciated. 
I cant spot the syntax error!

Error -

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.

My query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [User] INNER JOIN 
     [Order] ON [User].ID = [Order]​.UserId 
WHERE LEN([Address]​​.[Telephone]) = 10 
     AND ORDER.[Status] = 3
```

Comment: Here ORDER is consider as Keyword not as Table Name. change the name and try again.

Comment: Syntax highlighting plus the error message should be a big clue.

Comment: That looks suspiciously like an SQL Server error message - so is the [tag:mysql] tag correct here?

Comment: While first issue is "order" being a reserved word which needs to be quoted; the second issue will be inside the LEN function as the object [Address] isn't found in your from or join clauses or aliased through any other subquery, cte, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM [User]
 INNER JOIN [Order] ON [User].ID = [Order]​.UserId
 WHERE LEN([Address]​​.[Telephone]) = 10 AND [ORDER].[Status] = 3
```

Order is a **resereved keyword** in MySql so you need to escape it `[Order]`.

And I too agree with Damien_The_Unbeliever as the message looks like the SQL Server error rather than MySql although in **Sql Server** too `Order` is a reserved keyword!

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE player_first_name AS player_firstname,
       player_lastname   AS player_surname,
       course_name,
       tour_date
from   tournaments joining player_first_name,
       player_lastname,
       course_name,
       tour_date
WHERE  EXISTS
       (
                SELECT  *
                FROM     players
                WHERE    tournaments = t.winner
                ORDER BY tour_date ASC);
```

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same problem and was dumbfound and realized that "Order" is a reserve word in SQL server. You cant drop the Order Table when you have dependencies . So for now you can enclose it with in [Order].

Next time try using the table name "Orders" instead.

Comment: Though we thank you for your answer, it would be better if it provided additional value on top of the other answers. In this case, your answer does not provide additional value, since another user already posted that solution. If a previous answer was helpful to you, you should vote it up instead of repeating the same information.